# How to manage passwords in web applications?

Tags: java, mysql, passwords, password-protection

What is the current state of the art method for persisting users passwords in web applications? I am working with Java 6 + MySQL. Some of the questions I have in mind are: Is it better to encode in the app or by means of the DBMS (is this relevant at all)? Which algorithm is considered to be reliable? What to store in the database? Really new to this stuff, so might have missed some critical details in which case please do not hesitate to let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: I think the common framework hashes the password on the client or server side and stores the hash in a database. This hash is in case the database is compromised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should store **securely hashed** and **salted** version of passwords to the database. So that if your site is hacked, since users use the same pass almost everywhere their other accounts are not compromised.

To do this, the following should be done:

1. Use a secure hashing algorithm that is not yet broken (SHA-512 preferably, *Sha1 and MD5 are broken*)
2. Concatenate **Username+Password+Salt** (salt should be a relatively long constant string which is the same through the time on your application, and prevents Rainbow Attacks to some effort)
3. SHA-512 result of the concatenation and store it in the database.
4. everytime a user tries to login, hash his/her credentials using the same method and check against the data in the database, if the same, its correct.

It is not important where you hash passwords (App or DB) but DB's have limited secure hashing functionality, so app is the better choice.

Comment: -1: You want a salt **per hash**, not per application. That complicates greatly the generation of rainbow tables. A per application salt doesn't do much. A rainbow table for common words can be computed in a day or so.

Comment: Not much difference if the single salt is long enough. The salt is to prevent dictionary attacks.

Comment: I think you mean the right thing, but you might want to clarify your language to specify that the salt should be a *different*, but constant, string for each password being hashed. By "constant...same through the time on your application" I am guessing you do *not* mean a single constant value covering all strings to be hashed.

Comment: @AbiusX: The length of the salt has no incidence. If your application gets compromised (or in Java, "decompiled"), your salt is known and your protection is out. However, if you generate a random salt per hash, even if your salt is stored along-side your hash, a rainbow table has to be built for each password you want to find out.

Comment: You could also hash the password in the client browser to avoid sending the password over the internet in the clear if you're not using HTTPS (see http://jssha.sourceforge.net/ for a JS library to do SHA).

Comment: @WhiteFang34: That's pointless. An attacker can simply forge a request with the hashed password and gain access anyway.

Comment: @WhiteFang34: this adds no security, since the attacker would also send hash of the password instead of the original pass, i.e password is now its hash.

Comment: @Andrew: would you please specify to me how length of salt is meaningless and how the attacker knowing your salt can break protection?

Comment: @AbiusX: Knowing your salt, I can simply generate **ONE** rainbow table and check all your passwords against that. The length of your salt doesn't make it harder for me to generate a rainbow table or not. Also, chances are that if I have access to your database, I have access to your code where your "secure salt" is stored. This cannot happen with per-password salt. I have to generate a rainbow table for each password, and that's costly time wise (even more costly with a slow algorithm like `bcrypt`).

Comment: @Andrew: You are aware that generating a Rainbow Table requires as much effort as breaking a hash? That's not an option. Rainbow Tables are useful in general when generated and used for all hashes O(2^n)/O(2^n) = O(1), Also salts are not meant to be secure

Comment: @AbiusX: Every single security expert out there will tell you exactly what I'm saying: use a slow algorithm, don't reuse the same hash. Salts are used to make rainbow table generation harder.

Comment: Hashing the password in the client browser is not entirely pointless. It safeguards end users that tend to use the same password for different sites. Imagine for example if they used their gmail password and the login is their gmail address. An attacker in the middle can now steal their gmail account. Whereas if it was hashed specifically for a site it'd only be good on that site. Yes, it doesn't help the security of your own site any.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_salt#Additional_benefits Check this out. Also you can check out OWASP website, I'm considered a worldwide security expert.

Comment: @AbiusX: OWASP recommends `bcrypt` for the reasons above.

Comment: @WhiteFang: in your scenario right, but rainbow tables ruin that scenario. @Andrew: did you read the wikipedia post?

Comment: @AbiusX: I choose not to base security on anything Wikipedia says.

Comment: @Andrew: I'm not saying its true cuz wiki says so, There are reasons listed below that. And I told you why your assumption is wrong. Why are you so stubborn?

Comment: @AbiusX: [OWASP on salting each password individually](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cryptographic_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Rule_-_Store_the_hashed_and_salted_value_of_passwords)... But you are right, I'm wrong... Insults and unverified sources (which say the opposite of what you are saying) really helped you put your point across.

Comment: @Andrew: please check your link again. :)

Comment: @AbiusX: *"Store the salted hashed value of the password. **Salt each hash. Preferably use a different random salt for each password hash instead of a constant long salt.** Never store the clear text password or an encrypted version of the password. Cryptographic framework for password hashing is described in PKCS #5 v2.1: Password-Based Cryptography Standard. Specific secure password hashing algorithms exist such as **bcrypt**, scrypt."*

Comment: Yeah as you can see, it says preferably, as I said. Its not mandatory.

Comment: @AbiusX: furthering the value of client side hashing, the server could provide two salts: one that stays the same for a given user (U) and one that changes every session (S). The client hashes the user password with salt U and then hashes that with salt S. The server reads the hash from the database (that's only salted with U when the user sets their password) and hashes that with S to compare against for verification. Now rainbow tables can't be applied and the hash sent over the wire is only useful for the duration of the session.

Comment: @AbiusX - no, it's not mandatory. in fact, any type of salting is not mandatory. heck, even hashing is not mandatory. we could just store the passwords in plain text. on the other hand, hashing is a bit more secure than plain text, so it would be preferable. and salting the hash is a bit more secure, so it probably is also preferable. and seeing that salting with different salts per password hash is preferable to salting with a constant long salt according to people expected to know security, wouldn't the logical conclusion be that it _is_ indeed more secure?

Comment: @AbiusX - and if there is a choice of being more secure, why would you argue that the person recommending that choice is wrong and the OP should stay with the less secure (according to OWASP) choice? If anything, I might endeavor to call such a recommendation as "potentially too expensive for specific scenarios" (and this question is not one such scenario), but in no way I could see how it is wrong.

Comment: @WhiteFang: its called hash challenge.

Comment: @Franci: you should know the trade-off between performance and security. random salts add like .1% security. Hashing passwords adds like 90% security. If you don't hash your passwords, No security knowing person would join your site. If you dont random salt them, nobody really cares. You need to generate a rainbow table (which takes months in best scenario) to crack a constant salted pass. You need to spend less than a minute to crack a non hashed pass. You could always use hardware tokens and biometrics for authentication, and adds more sec, why dont you do that then?

Comment: @AbiusX - yes, there are always tradeoffs between performance and security. and proper evaluation of risk vs. mitigation costs should be done every time when someone decides what level of security they want. however, what should never be done is plainly dismissing security measures and proclaiming the person that suggested them as wrong. At the very least, you could've bothered to ask the OP how critical is the data behind that web site. it might be as well that hw token or biometrics _is_ the right level for them.

Comment: @AbiusX - on a side note - yes, some of our websites are using two factor auth with hw token being one of the factors. and yes, it is the right level of security given the data accessible through them.

Comment: @AbiusX - yes, that is true too. it's your call on how you want to spend your efforts. that still does not make @Andrew wrong with his suggestion that using a salt per password offers more security than using a single long salt for all passwords.

Comment: *that the salt should be a different, but constant, string for each password being hashed.* this is @Andrew and is not a suggestion!

Comment: @AbiusX: You quoted Ken Redler, not me. Also, rainbow tables, in today's world where computing power can be leased at a low cost, doesn't take months to compiled if paralleled properly. Just lease a few EC2 instances, you'll have a rainbow table compiled in a matter of days for a few dollars if the hashing algorithm is fast (the `sha` family is). Salting each password separately doesn't increase your cost, doesn't hurt application performance, doesn't increase complexity for users... So it increases your security, without any tradeoffs.

Comment: @Andrew: salting requires much more code to implement correctly, and btw, You should know about Merkles time memory tradeoff. To generate a working rainbow table for SHA-512 even with supercomputers you would need months.

Comment: @AbiusX: Right, because generating a random string, concatenating it with the hash, and substring-ing at check time is beyond most people's ability. And yes, in a single thread, it would take months. However, multithreading and cheap cloud-based computing makes that number go down. I have nothing to add to this conversation. You are obviously set in your ways. It's your prerogative.

Comment: @Andrew: I'm sorry that I mistook @Ken with you, And I might sound offensive when I'm not, so another sorry for that.

Answer (score 3):

`bcrypt` is a reliable algorithm for password hashing. It's been created by security professionals with security in mind.

`bcrypt` is slow (that's a good thing, makes rainbow tables creation a very costly). You can configure `bcrypt` with a variable amount of rounds to scale with whatever hardware you are using (more rounds = slower). Also, it automatically handles salt generation, a different salt per hash (which makes a rainbow table attack close to impossible, due to the slow nature of `bcrypt` and the fact that it would take a full rainbow table per password).

A Java implementation of `bcrypt` is available at [jBCrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/).

Answer (score 0):

You are going to face the wrath of, lot of self proclaimed security gurus, for asking an question like this. I myself, is not a security expert, but feel myself qualified enough to put forth some suggestions, driven by common sense. Depending on how secure you want your application to be, there are various methodologies.

1- Most of the attacks happen when you transfer credentials over wire. (Man in the middle stuff). So you need to make sure that the transfer of username and password should be made secure.  (ssl or HTTP Digest). If security is very important, then you should explore if the username \ password need to be passed at all. ( by using some token based authentication like Oauth instead of username and password)

2- In case, if you decide to pass in username and password, you need to reduce the lifetime of the password string, in your application scope. Of course the best method is to implement a authentication filter based on a mechanism like LDAP. Most LDAP  store, will allow you to store encrypted password and will allow you to perform authentication by binding.( so your application will never worry abt authentication and storing)

3- In case if you do bring your password to your application tier, of course you still need to reduce the lifetime of your plaintext password and encrypt using some secure hashing algorithm. But this approach and storing the password in your database (even in encrypted form) is not all that safe. ( especially, since you are storing the password, someone can circumvent your security layer)

So to summarize, based on the amount of security you need, you need to ask yourself the following question.

1- Should you need to send username / password?

2- Can you make sure that the password cannot be sniffed over the network?

3- Can you not delegate your authentication to a front filter, rather than bringing on to your application tier?

Comment: I am afraid that I might have digressed a bit. But the simple answer is "do not save password in your rdbms store". delegate this to an front filter. (in case of java application server jaas, or some library like spring security backed by a store like ldap)